# IOS .IPA stuck and not installing

Tags: ios, iphone

I am trying to test a beta version of a app that is being developed i was given a correct mobile provision file and a .IPA file. I followed instructions to install on my iphone but the install froze at 30%, After waiting for 30 minutes i reboot the phone and tried again at this point not even getting a loading bar.

After trying this several times i think the IPA is stuck on the phone , i have tried everything to remove it. I attempted in iTunes , rebooting then removing and in settings. Anyone have any experience with this issue?

Comment: Please cross check whether the provisioning profile includes your device or not.

Comment: After trying to solve this problem for two hours, I learned that the provisioning profile contains the UDID of the iOS hardware device you have.  And I realized, the UDID being inserted into the provisioning profile was incorrect.  I went to developer apple website and then I registered a brand new iOS device with correct UDID and it finally worked.  It made me dance for a minute.

Comment: After wrestling with this issue for roughly 12 hours I realized that the UDID of my iOS hardware device stored on Apple server was *incorrect,* and it gave me an *incorrect* provisioning profile.  I removed the device and I registered a brand new device with a correct UDID and it installed.    iTunes can tell you the correct UDID of your device.

Answer (score 0):

It should be related to your provisioning profile configuration issue. Please cross check the added devices in your provisioning profile. Once all done, **Re-build** and try again.